# How to get size of a Directory in node js using sync functions

Tags: javascript, node.js

im working on a server for a file explorer in node js ...and i want to get the size of directories im working with ..i can't use child_process , so i found this on http://npmjs.com :

```js
const getSize = require('get-folder-size');
 
getSize(myFolder, (err, size) => {
  if (err) { throw err; }
 
  console.log(size + ' bytes');
  console.log((size / 1024 / 1024).toFixed(2) + ' MB');
});
```

but its not working for my code .. i need to use "size" variable out of this function and i don't know how to put this out of the callback functions ? if there is a way for this or if there is another way for getting size of a directory

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you want to access the "size" value in a synchronous style. For that you need to wrap the `getSize` function into a promise, and use `async-await`, here is a simple example

```js
// example.js

const getSize = require('get-folder-size');

const getSizePromise = (myFolder) => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    getSize(myFolder, (err, size) => {
      if (err) {
        reject(err)
        return
      }
      resolve(size)
    })
  })
}

(async() => {
  const folderSize = await getSizePromise('./node_modules')
  console.log(folderSize)
})()
```

Comment: that was what i wanted .....thank you so much ...i was going to write a recursive function to calculate the size :))))...now i can solve this better :)

Answer (score 0):

Since it is a callback-based method, you need to have your logic in other function and invoke it inside this method callback and pass size parameter.

```
getSize(myFolder, (err, size) => {
  if (err) { throw err; }
 
  console.log(size + ' bytes');
  console.log((size / 1024 / 1024).toFixed(2) + ' MB');

  myFunc(size);
});

fumction myFunc (size) {
  ...logic here
}
```

Comment: i actually did try this ...but didn't worked ...i wanted to access size in a synchronous way ...thank u for your answer :)